# renaming routes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to this, so I'm not expecting that anyone tell me how to do it, just whether it's possible. If so, I'll continue to melt my brain with the docs.

I've been asked to change /markets/4/articles/32
to /markets/111111/articles/999999 where 111111 is in the remoteID field of the markets table and 999999 is in the remoteID field of the articles table.

The reason for this is that an external system will be creating the new records in the RoR app and inserting ITS id into the remoteID field. The next time it goes to update the record, it won't know the RoR ids without creating some kind of lookup.

From what I've seen, it can't be done. Maybe I'm just not looking hard enough?

Thanks,
Kelp

Comment: do you want to change the _helpers_ that generate such urls (such as e.g.  `market_article_path`) or the matching rules? Both should be possible. Take a look at the `to_param` method. Inside your app you could just do a `Article.find_by_remoteId(params[:id])`, is that not enough?

Comment: riffraff, your solution came to me last night while losing sleep over it. find_by_remoteId does indeed work for creating and updating through the API without mucking with the routing for people using the app(or me having to twiddle with the helpers).

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, it probably can be changed to something like:

```
/markets/:market_remote_id/articles/:article_remote_id
```

It will then be available as `params[:market_remote_id]` and `params[:article_remote_id]` in your controller

Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments for the full story